# Audio Port of laptop not working

Tags: windows-8, audio, lenovo-laptop, sound-card, headphone-jack

I am using Lenovo model G510 laptop and my audio port is not working properly.

I guess it may have broken.  As it is connected to the motherboard, I try not to disturb it.  So only option remains to check for alternatives.

And found this: [laptop headphone jack not working what are alternatives](http://deals.woot.com/questions/details/ee383e37-89c5-458d-9800-ac33251d51a9/are-there-any-alternatives-for-sound-out-if-a-laptop-headphone-jack-is-not-work).

[External Sound Card](http://www.amazon.in/Quantum-QHM623-USB-Sound-Card/dp/B007Z9K45U) just look at this link as so any suggestions
like this sort of problem indicate  this as the best but after careful
examination and reviews I came to conclusion it is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You state "is not working properly". If it's completely dead or the volume is extremely low, rather than the plug being loose or sound noisy when a jack is wiggled in the socket, it may just be a **sound setting**. Check not only the Windows *Sound* Control Panel applet, but also any sound add-ons, e.g. *SmartSound* congtrol if you have *Smart Audio* installed, Realtek settings etc.
2. If it is the physical connector at fault:

   a. Fix the audio output connector. Lenovo has the service manual for download at http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g400g500g405g505g410g510_hmm.pdf. This may require soldering on a multi-layer PCB, not for the inexperienced.

   b. Use HDMI output which combines video and audio. You'll need an HDMI device such as a monitor that has an earphone jack.

   c. USB audio adapter is probably the simplest solution, though you want an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Any USB Sound card should do the job for you, or some USB headphones. Cheap and simple to install. Some require no drivers, others require drivers to use all the features they offer.

There are a lot available. Examples here.
http://www.aliexpress.com/premium/usb-sound-card.html?ltype=wholesale&SearchText=usb+sound+card&d=y&origin=y&initiative_id=SB_20150207044845&isViewCP=y&catId=0

Comment: Iam asking for an alternative for this

Comment: You have a laptop, there are not many option available to you. Get it repaired or add a sound card and to be honest a USB one is the simplest option and incredibly cheap. What alternatives are you thinking of?

Comment: can we connect mobile to computer and headphones to phonw

Comment: You could use Bluetooth connectivity. Headphones and Speakers can be connected this way. Using your phone may not work, it really depends if your phone supports Audio playback via BTooth as phones are generally used to send/receive calls and to send music to a device, not receive it but that is not to say it is impossible, just depends on what BTooth services your phone allows.  I use Bluetooth Headphones and Speakers at times as it requires no additional adapters etc on notebook or tablet, thus making it simpler.